# Looking through an array for an empty string

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

An array of Strings, names, has been declared and initialized. Write the statements needed to determine whether any of the the array elements are null or refer to the empty String. Set the variable hasEmpty to true if any elements are null or empty-- otherwise set it to false.

```
   hasEmpty=false;
   for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
   if (names[i].trim().equals("") || names[i]==null)
   hasEmpty=true;
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: @ColinD what was edited?

Comment: I added the homework tag, as this reads like a homework assignment. If it's not, my mistake. But looking at your question history, I think you need to spend more time learning this yourself and a little less asking questions for every thing. If you take the time to figure some of these things out yourself, you'll probably end up understanding it better.

Comment: I only ask if I spend too much time on it..most of the answers I received were stuff that I would have never figured out on my own anyway..like checking for null before using trim. I would have never figured that out, even if I had spent hours on it..

Comment: I think you could have figured it out.

Comment: Actually this code was failing even without trim(), so even if I had names[i].equals(""), it was failing, so I probably would not have figured it out..

Comment: But did you consider the exception (`NullPointerException`) you were getting and what it might mean? Did you try different things to see what happened?

Comment: These are online exercise using TuringsCraft, so I wasnt using a normal IDE..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `trim()` first will result in a NullPointerException should a member of the array be `null`. Reverse the order of the conditions - the short-circuiting nature of `||` will then ensure that `trim` is only called on a real String object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `names[i].trim()`.

When `names[i]` is a String, you really have something like `someString.trim()` which works fine.

When `names[i]` is a null, however, you really have something like `null.trim()`.  You've already discovered that null doesn't allow a trim() method.  (In fact, I'm not even really sure what 'null' is.)

Therefore, you must check for null before you invoke trim().

When you have `a && b`, where `a` and `b` are expressions, the checks are made left-to-right and the parser stops as soon as the issue is settled.  So for the logical and operator (&&), if `a` is false then `b` is never checked.  This is what allows

```
if (a != null && a.trim().length() > 0) { ... }
```

to work.  if `a` is null, the a.trim() part is not executed since it would be pointless from a logical point of view; the value of the conditional has been decided.

Similarly for

```
if (a == null || a.trim().length() == 0) { ... }
```

if `a` is null then the a.trim() part is never performed and we don't get an error.

Comment: *" In fact, I'm not even really sure what 'null' is."* - See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.1

Comment: hehe I looked it up immediately upon posting.  It was pretty much what I thought but reading it is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Apache Commons Lang's isBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) to check a String:

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(names[i]) {
    ...
}
```

`StringUtils.isBlank` is checking if the String is `null` or empty (i.e. if it is equals to `""` when all blank characters are removed).

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing a Null Pointer Exception because you're trying to run a method on a null object:

```
if (names[i].trim().equals("") || names[i]==null)
```

So, anytime that names[] has ONE name that's null, it will throw the exception.  One way to solve the problem is to switch the boolean statements in this if statement:

```
if (names[i]==null || names[i].trim().equals(""))
```